# Request and Response mismatch in async callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, request

I'm fetching a lot of data asynchronously using "request" in Node.js.

First of all, the request callback does not contain the original request post parameters (which is horrible) so I had to implement this myself by adding an x-header to the request (because headers from the original request are available within the callback response).

However, the request headers often mismatch the response result. I.e. I request two URL's in quick succession and the callback will mix them up. It will claim that the request headers for one request belong to the result of the other request.

```
var getActiveGames = function() {

  console.log(activeGamePlayer);

  if (activeGamePlayer >= Object.keys(players).length-1) {
    activeGamePlayer = 0;
  }

  var player = Object.keys(players)[activeGamePlayer];

  var ign = players[player].ign;

  if (ign) {

    request.post({
      headers: {
        'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'x-summoner' : player
      },
      url:     URL,
      body:    'userName=' + ign + '&force=true'
    }, function(error, response, body){
      if (!error) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          jsdom.env(body, ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'], function(err, window) {
            if (window.jQuery) {

              activeGamePlayer += 1;

              var $ = window.jQuery;

              var isPlaying = $('div:first').hasClass('SpectatorBig');

              //var playerID = response.client._httpMessage._headers['x-summoner']; //doesn't work due to request and response headers mismatch


              var playername = isPlaying ? $('tr.mine .summonerName').html() : $('div.nBoxContent b').html();

              if (playername) {

                var playerID;

                for (var p in players) {
                  if (players[p].ign) {
                    if (players[p].ign == playername) {
                      playerID = p;
                    }
                  }
                }

                if (isPlaying) {
                  var champion = $('tr.mine div.__spc32').removeClass('__spc32 img').attr('class');
                  champion = champion.replace('__spc32-', '');
                  var gameURL = $('div.Spectate a').attr('href');
                  var timestamp;
                  if ($('._countdown').length) {
                    timestamp = $('._countdown').attr('data-timestamp');
                  } else {
                    timestamp =$('._timeago').attr('data-datetime');
                  }
                  players[playerID].activeGame = {
                    'timestamp' : timestamp,
                    'champion' : champion,
                    'finished' : false,
                  };
                } else {
                  if (players[playerID].hasOwnProperty('activeGame')) {
                    players[playerID].activeGame.finished = true;
                    // make sure no game is in players json object
                  }
                }
              } else {
                console.log ("Error: Faulty data from op.gg");
                faultyIGN = Object.keys(players).length;
              }

            } else {
              console.log("Error: No jQuery object in jsdom body.");
            }
          });
        } else {
          console.log("GetActiveGame: Status Code not 200");
        }
      } else {
        console.log("GetActiveGame: " + error);
      }
      setTimeout(getActiveGames, 100);
    });

  } else {
    //no ign
    activeGamePlayer += 1;
    setTimeout(getActiveGames, 100);
  }

}
```

The issue is that the response object in this instance contains incorrect information. The request and response information it contains do not match up, they are from separate requests and responses.

Comment: Can you provide a simplified, complete example that reproduces the particular problem? Also, if you need access to the body you sent, why not just pull that out into a variable that you can then also access it inside the callback?

Comment: The callback seems to be messing with the scope. If i put several of these in a for loop and set variables, they will get mixed up in the callbacks (i.e. the variable set in one instance of the loop will be accessible in the callback of a different loop instances callback) depending on timing.

Comment: You could always use a closure inside the for-loop to capture the current value of the body, that will fix that particular problem.

Comment: But every instance of the for loop is already a closure in itself, no?

Comment: No, control structures in JavaScript are not closures.

Comment: Hmm... I'm actually running a function through setInterval. Does each instance of this function not count as a scope either?

Comment: You should update your code example to show what you're actually doing so that a more relevant solution can be given.

Comment: Updated with code example. Not sure it will help because I'm such a messy coder (haven't coded in three years). Basically it's a scraper that checks if a player out of a list of players is online. The problem occurs because the callback claims that the wrong players are online due to the problems described. In the code example this is solved by extracting the players name from the target URL and converting it into an ID. This is problematic because it's not 100% that the player name exists on the target URL.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but for sure the problem is not a mix up of req and response headers. The `.post` would never do that. -- You seem to like for(...)-loops. Do you have any outside that `.post`, that ruins your values? If the loop counts eg `i` to the end, then `i` is on this value for all calls you already made.

Comment: It is the headers mixed up. If I read the request headers that are in the object "response" that is passed to the callback function, they will not be related to the response headers and body that are in that very same object. Why would request headers and response headers in the same object not match up? Ihis object somehow also contains references to other http requests that request.post has nothing to do with...

There were no for loops used. There is one in the example which is added as a fix because the response headers don't match up. Even that one couldn't produce these problems.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs

The trick is to wrap the callback in a self-executing function which is passed the information you wish to save. This information then becomes available to the callback functions closure.

```
for (pool in pools) {
var url = 'http://www.thprd.org/schedules/schedule.cfm?cs_id=' + pools[pool];
request(url, ( function(pool) {
    return function(err, resp, body) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        console.log(pool);
        // TODO: scraping goes here!
    }
} )(pool));
}
```